# Python Programming error . 'import sitecustomize' failed; use -v for traceback

Tags: python

Anything that I code I get this same error.   `import sitecustomize` failed; use -v for traceback. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2):

Do what the error message tells you to do; run Python from the command line with the [`-v` command line switch](http://docs.python.org/2/using/cmdline.html#miscellaneous-options) to get a traceback. There is an error in the `sitecustomize.py` module and you need to fix that.

Alternatively, set the [`PYTHONVERBOSE` environment variable](http://docs.python.org/2/using/cmdline.html#envvar-PYTHONVERBOSE) to get the same effect.

Comment: For anyone experiencing the same issue, I deleted all instances of sitecustomize.pyc